# Positioning image banner on a wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress

I am a newbie experimenting with Wordpress. Would like to know the answer for the following question:

In the following website : http://thejuicesensei.com/wp/
I have a picture in my header. On a full screen it looks ok but on mobile and when minimized the picture is on the left of the page. I would like it to be on the right. I thought that maybe I had to use CSS to reposition it so i did the following:

.widget-header img { float: left; } to .widget-header img { float: right; }

in hopes that it would work. However nothing seems to have changed. Did i select the wrong class or something? Any help would be appreciated and sorry if it sounds like such a basic question.

(currently using the splash theme for wordpress)

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

I want the image to be on the right so there isnt that ugly gap of white.

Regards

Comment: Below answer is working well for you or not?

Comment: Still working on it. CSS doesnt seem to be updating.. may be caching problems.. Will have to figure out how to make sure css edits are actually showing first..

Comment: Do one thing is just add below both thing in your custom css file and then also not working well then and then please add max-width: 45% !important after this process.

Comment: Hi Empiro, I dont want the option you gave, I just want the picture on the right when it minimizes.. if you can help it would be so great!

Comment: Then add float:right to this class .widget-header.

Answer (score 0):

Please add float:right to below class.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 728px){
    .widget-header {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Style parent of img from float:left to float:right

```
@media screen and (max-width: 728px){
  .widget-header {
    max-width: 100%;
    float: right; //change this
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```